# Parse CloudCode to remove user from PFRelation

Tags: ios, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I am new to Parse cloudcode and spinning my wheels to understand JS and write cloudCode to remove user from PFRelation. Can anyone please assist me with parse cloudcode snippet to remove user from PFRelation. I am trying to implement unfriend functionality in the iOS app and I can remove the friend from current users PFRelation and would like to remove current user from the friend PFRelation. I am completely blanked out and don't know how to do that.
I appreciate the help.
Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I gave an answer, but I just realized you wanted to use CloudCode.  I deleted by answer.

Answer (score 2):

The javascript info (that's what you need to do this function on the server) is here: https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#objects-pointers

Specifically, the code on that page that you need is:

```
var relation = request.user.relation("friends");
relation.remove(other);
request.user.save();
```

Then you need to get a handle to the other user object and do the same thing there. Are you storing Parse.User objects, or IDs? If it's User objects, the whole code could be this:

```
var relation = request.user.relation("friends");
var other = relation[0]; // I'm not sure about array indexing though.
var otherRelation = other.relation("friends");
otherRelation.remove(user);
relation.remove(other);
other.save();
request.user.save();
```

Note that this code isn't really kosher from the perspective of "when the function returns, the logic is done". It's not, since the save is asynchronous. It's faster this way. You could make it both fast and kosher by running both together and waiting for both to finish, but it's been a long time since I've written JavaScript so I can't provide the exact code for that.

Edit: Don't forget to use `Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey()` to get the right permissions before you try modifying another user.

Comment: In my main.js I already have a function in there which adds the friend to the PFRelation. Should just add another function to remove friends from PFRelation at the end of the first function?

Comment: Well here's the API for `Parse.Relation.remove()` in javascript: https://parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Relation.html#remove . But really, what's your goal? What's the problem? Maybe you can tell me what's the action that will prompt removal, and do you not have a handle to the friend that needs to be removed?

Comment: I am trying to do unfriend functionality. I can remove friends from currentUsers PFRelation, but to remove currentUser from the friends PFRelation I guess I need a JavaScript to run on the server.

Comment: Oh, I understand. Yes, that's correct. I think you should copy your function that adds the friend (in main.js) and make a version that unfriends. Call the function from the client, and remove the friend from the local user on the client (just so you don't get confused) but don't worry about saving, because the cloud function will save the data remotely.

Comment: With `var other = relation[0];`, you're selecting the first friend/relation. How would you select a specific relation, given the other user's ID?